# Select alternate points and move labels above/below

Tags: excel, vba

I am fairly new to VBA and trying to select alternating points to place datalabels above and below.

Here is my code that is currently placing a datalabel below point 1 which I want, but then I want the 3rd point's label to be placed below as well, and the other ones above. I have tried many different loops and codes but nothing seems to work and I'm not sure why it seems to copy and paste instead of move the label.

```
     For x = 1 To ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points.Count

        With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(x).DataLabel
             .Position = xlLabelPositionBelow
             .Orientation = xlHorizontal
        End With
    x = x + 2

    Next x

    For x = 2 To ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points.Count

        With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(x).DataLabel
            .Position = xlLabelPositionAbove                            
            .Orientation = xlHorizontal
        End With
    x = x + 2

    Next x
```

This is what my code currently produces:
[image]

Here is what I would like it to do:
[image]

I feel like it is something simple that I am missing if this is possible. So any help would be greatly appreciated. Is it possible there is an easier way?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you are 'over-iterating' x. Where you want x to go up by two, you're actually saying "x = x + 2" and THEN also saying "+ 1 x" (which is what Next does). You could solve this above by changing your For Loops to say "For x = 1 to 3 Step 2". Then when you loop with "Next x", it will add 2 instead of just 1.

However, I recommend you do it like the following, as it is (in my opinion) a little clearer that you want something for an even x, and something for an odd x:

```
 For x = 1 To ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points.Count
    With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(x).DataLabel
    If x Mod 2 = 1 Then 'If x is odd, put label below point

        .Position = xlLabelPositionBelow
        .Orientation = xlHorizontal
    Else 'if x is even, put label above point
        .Position = xlLabelPositionAbove
        .Orientation = xlHorizontal
    End If

    End With

Next x
```

Comment: This works perfectly and I appreciate your concentration to the details on my question! Just have to tweak a couple things but this will definitely help, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(1).DataLabel.Position = xlLabelPositionBelow
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(2).DataLabel.Position = xlLabelPositionAbove
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(3).DataLabel.Position = xlLabelPositionBelow

For x = 4 to ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points.Count
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(x).DataLabel.Position = xlLabelPositionAbove
Next
```

Comment: This does not alternate between top and bottom indefinately, which appears to be what OP wants.

Comment: In the question OP states: "...but then I want the 3rd point's label to be placed below as well, and the other ones above". So I assumed after the 3rd point all should be above.

Comment: There will be more than 4 points usually but this helped me realize a bigger issue I was able to solve as well so thank you!