# Moving data labels for two consecutive points

Tags: vba, excel

I have been trying to find a way to move data labels either above or below points.

Starting at point 1, for every two consecutive points, I'd like to move the data labels above the point, and for the next 2, I'd like to move them below. I'm not sure how to change my for loop or if statement to accommodate this condition. So in the end, the data labels for points 1 and 2 would be positioned above, the data labels for points 3 and 4 would be positioned below, 5 and 6 above...etc

If anyone can help, I'd greatly appreciate it.

```
Dim FlowIndex As Long

    With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1)
        For FlowIndex = 1 To .Points.Count 
        With .Points(FlowIndex)
            If .HasDataLabel Then
                With .DataLabel
                    .Position = xlLabelPositionAbove
                    .Orientation = xlHorizontal
                End With
            End If
        End With
    Next
End With
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select alternate points and move labels above/below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31857625/select-alternate-points-and-move-labels-above-below)

Comment: Note that you will need to change the loop method slightly from that question - instead of checking if something is odd or even, you will need to check if something / 4 either rounds up to 1 or down to 0.

Comment: I was just wondering if there's something I can change like instead of going to the next x, repeat for the next x and then change after the 2nd x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a mathematical question of how to perform your loop. Think of the values 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8. What mathematical rule would put 1,2,5,6 in the same group, and 3,4,7,8 in another group?

Possible answer: when divided by 4, 1 & 2 round down to 0. 3 & 4 round up to 1. 7&8 round up to 3. So, one group rounds up to an even number, and one group rounds down to an odd number. There are many ways to reflect this principle, but here is one:

```
IF FlowIndex MOD 4 = 1 OR FlowIndex MOD 4 = 2 then 'There is a remainder of 1 or 2 when divided by 4 - put label above
      'Do stuff
Else 'There is a remainder of 3 or 0 when divided by 4 - put label below
      'Do other stuff
End If
```

To clarify on my answer to the last question you had, MOD is a method of dividing which returns the remainder after doing whole number division. So 5 MOD 3 is 2, 9 MOD 3 is 0, etc.

Comment: Note that the way I jumped to this method of determining the grouping, is that you have a pattern that repeats every 4 iterations. Using the MOD approach is one of the simpler ways to reduce a repeating pattern to a single scalable test, and I chose to simply set the divisor at 4, because that's when the pattern repeats.

Answer (score 0):

Divide

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
```

by 2, and round up, to get:

```
1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4
```

Then you can test whether`1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4` is odd or even. If odd, then label above. If even, then label below.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

```
bLabelAbove = True

For i = 0 to 20 step 2      
    For j = 1 to 2
        If bLabelAbove Then
            Series.DataLabels(i + j).Position = xlLabelPositionAbove
        Else
            Series.DataLabels(i + j).Position = xlLabelPositionBelow
        End If
    Next

    bLabelAbove = Not bLabelAbove
Next
```